# Function for encryption/decryption - What is $n \phi(n)$?

Tags: cryptography

In my notes there are the following functions of encryption/decryption:

$$E_k(x)=x+k$$

$$D_k(y)=y-k$$

($E_k : \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$)

($D_k : \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$)

$$E_k(x)=ax+b, a\in \mathbb{Z}_n^{\star} , b \in \mathbb{Z}_n$$

$$D_k(y)=a^{-1}(y-b)$$

($E_k : \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$)

($D_k : \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$)

where $k$ is the key, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

$n \phi(n)$

$$y_1=ax_1+b \\ y_2=ax_2+b$$

$$\Rightarrow y_1-y_2=a(x_1-x_2) \\ \Rightarrow a=(y_1-y_2)(x_1-x_2)^{-1}$$

For example $$y_1=a(x+1)+b \\ y_2=ax+b$$

Could you explain to me what $n \phi(n)$ is??

In my notes there is only the notation, there isn't any explanation for what it stands...

Comment: All your last 10 questions (not to go too far in the past) received an upvoted answer, none of them got accepted. Would you  mind either accepting them or let the answerers know how they can improve on their work? Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the page you copied this from ?

Comment: Wow, what a way to make cryptography boring!

Comment: Were you in the classroom when you took these notes?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the idea is that in the second example the key is the pair $(b, a)$, where $b \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, and $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}^{\star}$, that is, $a$ in an invertible element in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Now $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ has $n$ elements, and $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{\star}$ has $\varphi(n)$ elements, where $\varphi$ is [Euler's $\varphi$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), so all in all you have $n \, \varphi(n)$ keys here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will helpful [Euler function, page 4](http://www.claysturner.com/dsp/totient.pdf). I have the course of cryptography so this function seems to me as an Euler function.